# Send confirmation email when a CustomerUser is registred

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to create a CustomerUser as a **Non-Authenticated Visitors** using a new storefront developped in Angular.
So when i send this request [/api/customerusers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd8pI.png) a customeruser is created but it's locked and no email is sent to activate it ( not catched in MailCatcher). I found in Orocommerce a Email template called "customer_user_confirmation_email" so i thought its already added in the backend no need to create anything.
But when i tried UI of Orocommerce 'DEMOB2B' the confirmation email is sent when a user is registred.
I don't know why it is working in Orocommerce demo but not in mine.
I checked in **System Configuration > Application Settings > Mail Configuration** everything is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To use the MailCatcher in OroCommerce, update `config/parameters.yml` file in your application and set:

```yaml
mailer_transport: smtp
```

If you are using the MailCatcher with non default port, then you'll also have to update the `mailer_port` option.